# Sum of certain items in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm working on a probability-related problem. I need to sum only specific items on a certain list.

I've tried using "for" functions and it hasn't worked. I'm looking for a way to select items based on their positions on the list, and summing them.

Comment: Give a [mcve], not just *"hasn't worked"*.

Comment: How do you select the items based on index? Please share your criteria so that we can help. Thank you.

Comment: You can iterate over a list and get the index of each element at the same time by using `for index, elem in enumerate(my_list):`.

Comment: Please provide some details as to what you’re filtering and what’s not working as well as expected outcome if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `operator.itemgetter` to select only certian index’s in a list or keys in a dict.

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
get_indexes = itemgetter(2, 5, 7)
#this will return indexes 2, 5, 7 from a sequence 
sum(get_indexes(data)) #3+6+8
#returns 17
```

That example is for lists but you can use itemgetter for dict keys too just use `itemgetter('key2', 'key5', 'key7')({some_dict})`

To get only even or odd indexes use slicing not enumerate and a loop it’s much more efficient and easier to read:

```
even = sum(data[::2])
odd = sum(data[1::2])
```

You can also use filter but I wouldn’t suggest this for getting by index:

```
sum(filter(lambda n: data.index(n) % 2 == 0, data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should have put more into your question, but:

```py
stuff = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# sum the numbers that have even indices:
funny_total = sum([x for i, x in enumerate(stuff) if i % 2 == 0 ])

funny_total
# 16
```

That should get you started. An approach with a `for` loop would have worked, as well. You just likely have a bug in your code.

```py
stuff = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
indices_to_include = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
funny_total = 0
for i, x in enumerate(stuff):
    if i in indices_to_include:
        funny_total += x
```

You could also:

```py
def keep_every_third(i):
    return i % 3 == 0
# variable definitions as above...
for i, x in enumerate(stuff):
    if keep_every_third(i):
        # do stuff
```